# Best practice for removing an object from its parent list?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

This is a pattern I've run into several times and I've searched around but haven't found a consensus on what the best approach is.

```
public class ItemListWrapper
{
    public List<Item> Contents;
}

public class Item
{
   void DoStuffAndRemove() { }
}
```

When DoStuffAndRemove() is called, I want the item to perform some function and then be removed from the ItemListWrapper. The two approaches I can think of are having ItemListWrapper implement IList (doable, but kind of annoying to have to have to write all that boilerplate code) and passing a delegate to each item to call which removes itself from the list (seems very convoluted).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why implement `IList`? You can define only a `Remove` method in `ItemListWrapper` without implementing the entire interface.

Comment: What's wrong with the good old ` DoStuffAndRemoveFrom(List<Item> listFromWhichTheItemIsToBeRemoved)`? You could then call it with `myItemListWrapper.Contents`, and remove all doubt about the list from which the item has to be removed.

Comment: Is a Queue or a Stack possibly a more appropriate data strcuture than a List? If your application desires FIFO for instance, you would simply execute `DoStuff(queue.Dequeue());`.

Comment: like @PieterGeerkens said - question is how you use it really - do you have some test case scenario? Do you store long-term, this seems a one-off approach (for which you have better options), how do you access them to 'do the job', sequential etc.

Comment: The ItemListWrapper is stored long-term to manage a group of objects, which are randomly and infrequently accessed to do some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you *must* have this `ItemListWrapper` for other reasons. Let's look at 2 approaches:

**1. Each item has a reference to it's list**

```
public class ItemListWrapper
{
    public List<Item> Contents;

    public void Add(Item item){ item.List = this; this.Contents.Add(item); }
}

public class Item
{
   ItemListWrapper List;
   void DoStuffAndRemove() { this.List.Contents.Remove(this); }
}
```

**2. Let the list control everything**

```
public class ItemListWrapper
{
    public List<Item> Contents;

    public void DoStuffAndRemove(Item item)
    { 
        if(this.Contents.Contains(item))
        {
            item.DoStuff();
            this.Contents.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
   void DoStuff() { ... }
}
```

IMHO, 2nd is better because *I understand* that the list must hold responsability for its items.

Comment: Note that in both cases they only work when direct access tot he list is prohibited by making them private.

Comment: @Servy Actually, 2nd option will work even if the list is made private, because it's implemented inside `ItemListWrapper`. Anyway, there could be a method such as `void RemoveIfContains(Item item)`